# IntelliJ 15 and Grails 3: unable to find grails packages

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, dependency-management

I'm converting a grails 2 plugin to grails 3, using IntelliJ 15.0 Community Edition.  **For Java files only**, IntelliJ gives me many errors about missing packages and symbols from Grails.  For example:

`Error:(20, 19) java: package grails.core does not exist`

and

`Error:(23, 41) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class AbstractGrailsClass`

I have tried adding dependencies in Project Structure so as to point to the grails sources, but that didn't seem to have any effect.  I admit I am a novice when it comes to IntelliJ, so this may be a simple config setting.

Answer (score 2):

In IntelliJ's preferences set up a Grails SDK Home. Open Preferences then type Grails to bring up the page. Then set it to point to your Grails installation e.g.

```
/Users/whoever/.sdkman/candidates/grails/current
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am running the CE version, which does not have explicit Grails support

Comment: I didn't think the CE supported Grails.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to consider is that Grails 3 requires moving .java files from src/main/java to src/main/groovy

This may be related to why you are experiencing problems.